# Rails: Webpack-dev-server has unmet peer dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am currently trying to set up a Rails 6.0.2 application on Ubuntu 18.0.4 using Docker. I have successfully set up the database using PostgreSQL and I have installed the necessary gems by running the command below:

```
bundle install
```

However, when I try to install the node packages using the command below:

```
yarn install
```

I get the message below which gives me some concern that something is not right:

> warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.10.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
>
> warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".

I have tried a few solutions but they're not working. What can I try next?

Comment: Those are warnings, you shouldn't care too much, the Rails webpacker people are taking care of updating versions of webpack.

Comment: Yeah, you're right that they are warnings, I just was not comfortable with them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Here's how I solved**:

Simply run the command below to upgrade the version of yarn to your desired version:

```
yarn upgrade webpack@^4.0.0
```

**Note**: You can substitute `4.0.0` with the required version for `yarn`, say `5.0.0`.

**Another Solution**

Add the version of webpack that you want to your `package.json` file. Here the version of webpack used is `4.43.0`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "webpack": "^4.43.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
}
```

And then run `yarn install` to install `webpack`

**For Docker Applications only**:

Add the command just before the `yarn install` command in your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN yarn upgrade webpack@^4.0.0 \
    yarn install
```

Reference to this on GitHub: [Unmet peer dependencies](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1078)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**.

Comment: You should not add this `RUN` command to your `Dockerfile`. After having upgraded your package, your `yarn.lock` file will know about the version you want to install. That's not the role of the `Dockerfile` to do that. The `Dockerfile` is here to prepare your environment, not to configure your application.

Comment: While I agree with you to an extent, I, however, think that the command  `RUN yarn upgrade webpack@^4.0.0` does not configure your application, it is rather preparing your application environment by setting up `yarn` in your application environment. Just like the command `RUN gem install bundler -v 2.1.4` sets up the `Bundler` gem in your application environment.

Comment: So what's the point of `yarn.lock` in the case you would be right?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded packages one at a time but kept getting the same warnings.

So I ran:

```
yarn upgrade
```

and next time I ran this all the warnings messages there were there previously had gone away:

```
yarn install
```