# Fresh Install of Rails not installing webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

A fresh install of rails 6.0.3.1 is giving me this warning:

`webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0"`

and when i run bin/webpack-dev-server i get the following error:

```
throw err;
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
```

Webpacker is in the gem file and webpacker:install was executed in the initial setup

Update:
After upgrading webpack i've noticed that now it cannot find @rails/webpacker. Looking at the logs on a fresh install i noticed this error:

```
error browserslist@4.14.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^6 || ^7 || ^8 || ^9 || ^10 || ^11 || ^12 || >=13.7". Got "13.3.0"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails: Webpack-dev-server has unmet peer dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565543/rails-webpack-dev-server-has-unmet-peer-dependency)

Comment: so looking at the issue again i've noticed the problem appears to be this error message when doing an install:
error browserslist@4.14.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^6 || ^7 || ^8 || ^9 || ^10 || ^11 || ^12 || >=13.7". Got "13.3.0"

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if rails/webpacker was not installing because i had an old version of node. I simply had to update my versionof node using nvm. Once updated, everything else was done and the server was upgraded.